# How to check a number is armstrong or not using php?

Tags: php

I made a program to check whether a number  is a amstrong number or not in php. But it is not working. Cloud anyone tell me what is wrong in this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="New Text Document.php" method="post">
        <input type="number" placeholder="number" name="amst">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
    if(empty($_POST)){
        exit;
    }

    # storing the input in a variable called amst
    $amst = $_POST['amst'];

    # storing the length of the input in a variable called len
    $len = strlen($amst);


    $add = 0;

    while($amst<=0){
        $div = $amst%10;
        $pow = pow($div,$len);
        $add+=$pow;
        $amst = intval($amst/10);
    }

    #printing the add.
    echo $add;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I printed add just to see whether it is working properly or not. Here no matter what the input is the answer is 0. I am only getting 0. Could anyone tell me why I am getting the output as 0. I have implemented amstrong number program in other languages. This is the method I use. But here it is not working.

Comment: Please reply...

Comment: Hi, check my reply answer

Answer (score 0):

Your loop requires a negative number. It works only if number <0, try :

```
$add = 0;

while($amst>0){
    $div = $amst%10;
    $pow = pow($div,$len);
    $add+=$pow;
    $amst = intval($amst/10);
}

#printing the add.
echo $add;
if ($add=== $_POST['amst']) {
  echo ‘This is an amstrong number’;
} else {
  echo ‘Nope’;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number is Armstrong not using blow code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="number" placeholder="number" name="amst">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
    if(empty($_POST)){
        exit;
    }
    
    $num = $originalNum = $remainder = $result = 0;
    
    # storing the input in a variable called amst
    $num = (int)$_POST['amst'];
    $originalNum = $num;
    
    for($i=1;$i<=strlen($originalNum);$i++){  
        // remainder contains the last digit
        $remainder = (int)$originalNum % 10;
        //store sum of each number's cube
        $result += (int)($remainder * $remainder * $remainder);
        // removing last digit from the orignal number
        $originalNum /= 10;    
    }
    
    if ($result == $num):
        echo $num." is an Armstrong number.";        
    else:
        echo $num." is not an Armstrong number.";
    endif;    
?>
</body>
</html>
```